# Download counter of exe file in PHP

Tags: php, download, counter

I have a problem with counting downloads of file. There will be no problem if a link to the download file would look like this: http:// your.site.domain/download.php?file=filename.exe&customer=ABC_423. However my customer want to count statistics from link like this: http:// your.site.domain/downloadsfolder/ABC_423/filename.exe and also he needs to hotlink that link on other sites.

I think there would be solution in .htaccess file, but I don't know how to make a proper redirect.

My PHP script looks like this:

```
session_start();
define('SERVER_NAME', 'www.siteaddress.domain');
define('DOWNLOAD_PATH', 'http:// siteaddress.domain/versions/download');
define('DOWNLOAD_FILE', 'Setup.exe');

$filename = DOWNLOAD_PATH . '/' . $_GET['customer'] . '/' . DOWNLOAD_FILE;

$headers = get_headers($filename);

if ($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'){
  // file exists, begin download procedure
  if(isset($_GET['customer'])){
    // begin update statistics
    // mysql query to update specified row
  }
  // headers for downloading file
  header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
  header('Content-Type: application/x-unknown');
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
  //header("Content-Type: application/download"); // not sure if needed
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($filename).";");
  header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  header("Content-Length: ".remote_filesize(SERVER_NAME, $filename));
  ob_clean();
  flush();
  readfile($filename);
  exit;
}else{
  echo 'File not found';
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess`. Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^/downloadsfolder/(.*)/(.*)     /download.php?file=$2&customer=$1    [L]
```

Observe how a random char sequence is detected with `(.*)` and then used with `$1` and `$2` for each detected item in the translated URL.

Hope that helped!

Comment: I've tried this but I'm getting loop because header function in download.php makes redirect to that file again. So the .htaccess will redirect with infinite loop...

Comment: Please, change the `DOWNLOAD_PATH` to a local path, not a URL. That's the reason for the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. It helped me a lot and I'll try this method you mentioned above.